# WPF/C#/XAML IsDefault Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button defined in *XAML* as follows:

```
<Button IsDefault="True" FontSize="12" Margin="312,16,155,3.6" Height="28" Name="SaveButton" Width="99" Click="SaveButton_Click">Save</Button>
```

In my `SaveButton_Click` method, I received two arguments:  the sender and the event.

Is it possible to determine whether or not the submit method was invoked because of a click on the button or because of hitting the *Enter* key?

Comment: You can check my solution it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes You can.

```
           if (InputManager.Current.MostRecentInputDevice is KeyboardDevice)
                MessageBox.Show("Enter key");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Mouse click");
```